# How do you get a list of pydoc accessible paths for a python package, e.g. numpy or tensorflow?

Tags: python, pydoc

I am trying to get all the paths in a python package (for example numpy) that you can use pydoc on. Ideally, this list would contain elements like:

numpy
numpy.linalg
numpy.linalg.det
...

So, ideally one would recurse into submodules and classes inside the package, and these paths would be what tab completion would give you in an enabled editor. I would prefer to get this list from the installed packages for consistency.

The purpose of this list is to feed it to a fuzzy completion engine to select items to then send to pydoc, eg. by typing "det", the engine would select all entries containing that string (so I don't have to remember the full path to it), and I could choose the one I want from there. That part is easy, once I have the list of paths! It doesn't matter if this is slow, I only need to do it once and can save it to file for use later. It also doesn't matter if the list is very long. The completion engine can handle very large lists.

Is there a straightforward way to do this? I have tried a few variations with the inspect module, recursing through the **dict** attributes, even one with rlcompleter, but so far I have either not had much success with the recursion, or the paths are not useful in pydoc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to do just that.
For example, for NumPy:

```
from pkgutil import walk_packages
import numpy

# Obtain list with all modules found in the package
mod_list = [name for _, name, _ in walk_packages(numpy.__path__,
                                                 numpy.__name__+'.')]
```

This will give you a list `mod_list` that contains all submodules that the NumPy package has, given in strings.

Comment: That is pretty close, thanks. It only lists the modules, and not the functions on the classes in them. For tensorflow, I found it useful to use the onerror function of walk_packages to avoid Exceptions related to an import.

It doesn't do quite what I need for tensorflow though. For example, the tensorflow.nn.relu function gets printed out as tensorflow.python.ops.gen_nn_ops.relu. The first one you can access the documentation via pydoc, but not the second one. You can also not import the second one in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, from your comment, you mean all `type`s that pydoc traverses?

Pydoc does limit it's documentation to the `__all__` list, but I'm pretty sure that if `__all__` equaled one class, it would still document the class's methods, etc, which are types in their own right.

```py
    import numpy
    print(numpy.__all__)
```

I would try to use pydoc's type traversal code, but it so mixed up with UI concerns that it doesn't really work well as a "better" `inspect` module.  Short of forking pydoc and modifying the type traversal code until you can create a "type" accumulator, I'm not sure this is possible.